# Issues running Apple Watch glance app in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, apple-watch

I'm trying to test my apple watch glance for my `iOS` app using the simulator, however I'm getting some very strange behaviour. When I launch the `iOS` app in the `simulator` it works without problem and the app is fully functional. However , when I then try to launch the glance app for apple watch afterwards it shows up, but the `iOS` app no longer works (if I try to launch it from the `simulator` it immediately crashes) and the data that's in the app sharing group doesn't show up on the watch (but if I relaunch the `iOS` app `simulator` from `Xcode` it shows up there).

I've checked both apps and they are configured for the same sharing groups and that is definitely the case.

I just don't understand why running the `iOS` app and the apple watch app in the `simulator` won't work / behave correctly together?

Comment: if you're using watchos 2 appgroup the system does not work on the device, you should use wcsession as the documentation indicates

Comment: @WhiteTiger Yes I'm using watchos 2.0 in conjunction with appgroups. Which documentation are you referring to? I've been looking around but didn't come across anything that described the issue I'm having (maybe I overlooked it...)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH29-SW1 app group is limited to watchapp watchextendion communication for the new architecture proposed by watchos 2

Comment: Thanks @WhiteTiger I'll look at updating to use the `WatchConnectivity` approach instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @WhiteTiger for this answer:

if you're using watchos 2 appgroup the system does not work on the device, you should use wcsession as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH29-SW1) indicates.

Or look at updating to use the `WatchConnectivity` approach instead